# How To Change Organization Account To Personal Account On Github

Tags: github, github-pages

I accidentally changed my github account which was originally my personal to an organizational account, when I was going to log back in my github account was lost and had to create a new one, how do I return my organization to my personal account?

```
this is my organization's github account which i want to revert back to being me personally back : https://github.com/aripin2401
```

I want to restore my github account to a personal account agai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way. The conversion is clearly in the danger zone and last time I tried it spelled out the rules quite clearly.

> Warning: Before converting a user into an organization, keep these points in mind.
>
> - You will no longer be able to sign into the converted personal account.
> - You will no longer be able to create or modify gists owned by the converted personal account.
> - An organization cannot be converted back to a user.

But what you can do it create a new user, then transfer your repos back to that user one-by-one, by transferring ownership and closing the organization.

Then, I believe after 90 days you can reclaim the username, unless someone beats you to it.